# how do I make a query of a user's uploaded files

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm a django newbie trying to finish a upload/download app. I am Using django-registration-redux for user reg/auth and have the following simple model. I've read the docs but haven't been able figure out how to query on a User's related fields namely, fields of a model with foreignkey to User.
here's my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

FileUploads(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    docfile = models.FileField(nul=True)
    docfileuuid = models.UUID()
```

My question being: Having a specific username, How can I query the list of his/her docfiles?

What I want to accomplish is when the user logs in and navigates through a view let's call it 'localhost:/yourfiles', s/he can be provided a list of his files.

In case of having no owner with foreign key to user, I used the following code to retreive the path to the all uploaded files:

```
obj = FileUploads.objects.all
uploads = [i.docfile for i in]
```

Now instead of all the docfiles, I want the ones that belong to the logged-in user.

I read the docs and tried things like:

```
obj = User.objects.all()
obj.fileuploads_set.all()
```

But no luck

Comment: `FileUploads.objects.filter(owner=user)` for querying upload files for logged in user. You can get the logged in user in view.py by accessing `request.user` variable.

Comment: I don't understand your second part of the question. If a user doesn't have any files, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I tried the code in shell, but I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'amir' where amir is the username.

Comment: @ShangWang I the user has no file, nothing special, each user get's to see his files, if none exists, he sees none

Comment: Check out my answer, you just need a simple funciton view and a filter for your models. @Miind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all files belong to a user by querying the username, do:

```
FileUploads.objects.filter(owner__usename='amir')
```

In your views.py, you would do:

```
uploads = FileUploads.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

Comment: All the answers were true, I'm accepting yours since you answered me first and covered my shell problem as well, than you very much

Answer (score 3):

When a user logs in your application, you do have user object in `request.user`

In your views.py,

```
def file_list_view(request):
    # This gives you list of file objects.
    files = FileUploads.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {'files': files})
```

In your template file

```
<ul>
   {% for file in files %}
       <li>{{ file.file_name }}</li> 
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple function view with a context dictionary. Filter the files in your model by the current user logged in which you can get by `request.user`. And then in your template use a for loop to print all file urls that user has, and by using the `{% empty %}` template tag to show a message whenever a user doesn't have any files uploaded.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def userfiles(request):

    context_dict = {}
    files = FileUploads.objects.filter(owner=request.user) 
    context_dict['files'] = files 

    return render(request, 'users_files.html', context_dict, )
```

the template:

```
{% for file in files %}
  file.docfile.url
{% empty %}
You don't have any files uploaded yet. 
{% endfor %}
```